# In my directory structure,I want to use the api_libs in my tests file. Can someone help me on right way to import?

Tags: python, directory

my tests are at:

```
src/com/hello/tests/api/api_test.py
```

my api libraries are at:

```
src/com/hello/libs/api_libs/common_api_libs.py
```

I want to use my Libs as part of my tests but not sure what is the right way to import it.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: add `__init__.py` file to your project root directory and sub-directories. And use relative import between them.

Python module/packages are well-explained on https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/.